# ASP.NET Core - Razor not checking for view embeded in assembly

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to set up a pair of .NET Core project where one is a class library including a ViewComponent and the other is an ASP.NET Core MVC application which makes use of that component.

I followed the guide here: http://www.strathweb.com/2016/01/re-using-external-view-components-in-asp-net-5-asp-net-mvc-6/

However, I can't seem to get this working. I keep getting:

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Components/Test/Default' was not
>   found. The following locations were searched:
>   /Views/Home/Components/Test/Default.cshtml
>   /Views/Shared/Components/Test/Default.cshtml

The component itself:

```
public class TestViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public TestViewComponent()
    {
    }

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The corresponding view (file path is Views/Shared/Components/Test/Default.cshtml):

```
<p>Hello from test component</p>
```

Relevant bit from ConfigureServices to tell Razor to look for views in the assembly:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
{
    o.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(
        typeof(TestViewComponent).GetTypeInfo().Assembly, "Test.Components"));
});
```

project.json from the class library project:

```
"buildOptions": {
  "embed": {
    "include": [ "Views" ]
  } 
},
```

and finally, at the bottom of _Layout.cshtml in the MVC project:

```html
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Test")
</body>
</html>
```

Things I've tried:

- Moving Default.cshtml for the component into the correct location in the MVC project. This gets things working fine so I'm pretty sure it's just a problem with Razor finding the view.
- Checking the view has been embedded into the assembly properly. I used `GetManifestResourceNames()` and it was listed as `MiddlewareTest.Views.Shared.Components.Test.Default.cshtml` so that looks fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it working by removing the base namespace.

`o.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(TestViewComponent)
                    .GetTypeInfo().Assembly));`

It seems that adding the base namespace doesn't work as expected. Don't really know why

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was resolved by changing `Build Action` property on the `View` from `None` to `Embedded Resource`.

1. Right click view in `Solution Explorer`.
2. Select `Properties`.
3. Change `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`.

Alternatively, if you want to automatically add all `Views` as `Embedded Resources`, you can add this `ItemGroup` to your `.csproj` file:

`<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\**\*.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: I had a problem with the view not being embedded until I created a resource file with a single string entry. You can also call a standard view directly in the controller action rather than using an intermediate ViewComponent.